# How to convert a pdf file to bytecode in php

Tags: php

Dear I want to convert a pdf file to bytecode to send the byte code through json but I am not able to convert the pdf to bytecode in php if there are any solutions please assist me..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

`file_get_contents` will get you the whole file into a string.

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents($file);
```

`str_split` will convert it into an array of one-character strings.

```
$byteArray = str_split($fileContents);
```

You can check official [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjGqaKWi5v5AhXthv0HHVc7AsQQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.file-get-contents.php&usg=AOvVaw3X4EL5FD1qwPEtQ05fAgfh) as well.